# ¿Mejor manera de decir: "como parte de"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Quiero decirle a alguien algo como:

- "como parte de nuestros estudios..."
- "ayudado por nuestros estudios..."
- "para complementar y mejorar nuestros estudios..."
- "en el cuadro de nuestros estudios" (traducción directa, podría ser falsa como frase)

En inglés:

- "Within the scope of our studies we decided to undertake this humanitarian project"
- "As a complement to our current education we decided to undertake this humanitarian project"

Pero no sé la mejor manera de decir una frase como estas de aquí. ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de escribirlo? No me limito a las 3 de aquí, son ejemplos, pero quiero decir casi la misma cosa.

Comment: Cualquiera de las frases podría ser correcta dependiendo de lo que quieras decir. Si puedes especificar la frase completa o incluso ponerla en inglés creo que podrás obtener una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Dicho en otras palabras, las 3 son gramaticalmente correctas, pero significan distintas cosas.

Comment: @SergioRomero nuevo edit en la pregunta, gracias! jachguate lo sabe pero quiero saber cual es lo mejor en este caso porque puedo adaptar lo que escribo un poco :)

Comment: @Oyibo creo que quieres decir "como complemento a nuestros estudios", que quedaría como "Hemos decidido tomar este proyecto humanitario como complemento a nuestros estudios"

Comment: Respecto de la última:  _"en el cuadro de nuestros estudios"_. En español suena mucho mejor "En el marco de nuestros estudios" o "Enmarcado en nuestros estudios"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Within the scope of our studies we decided to undertake this humanitarian project"*
>   "Dentro del alcance de nuestros estudios decidimos emprender este proyecto humanitario"
>   Comentarios:
>   1) Aunque menos literal, probablemente sea mas idiomático en español remplazar "emprender" por "incluir".
>   2) "Decidimos" tiene el típico problema del pretérito igual al presente ("yo decido, ... nosotros decidimos" y "yo decidí,... nosotros decidimos"). Para ser más claro podría utilizarse "hemos decidido".
>
> *"As a complement to our current education we decided to undertake this humanitarian project"*
>   "Como complemento de nuestra educación en curso hemos decidido emprender este proyecto humanitario"

Answer (score 3):

Las mejores alternativas a "como parte de" en el contexto de "ofrecemos u organizamos algo, que forma parte de otra cosa más grande que también ofrecemos" son las siguientes:

- Dentro del ámbito de (también "en el ámbito de")

  > **Dentro del ámbito** de X ofrecemos Y.
  >
  > *Dentro del ámbito de nuestros estudios hemos decidido emprender este proyecto.*
  >   *En el ámbito del programa "Año de los Pueblos Americanos" se organizará la conferencia "Cocina Andina".*
- En el marco de

  > **En el marco de** X ofrecemos Y.
  >
  > *En el marco de nuestros estudios hemos decidido emprender este proyecto.*
  >   *La conferencia "Cocina Andina" se organiza en el marco del programa "Año de los Pueblos Americanos*".

  Una variante es usar el verbo enmarcar o [encuadrar](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=encuadrar&origen=REDRAE).

  > *Este proyecto se enmarca en el ámbito de nuestros estudios.*
  >   *La conferencia "Cocina Andina" se encuadra en el programa "Año de los Pueblos Americanos*".

Answer (score 1):

Ya con la frase en inlgés completa te puedo decir que las siguientes opciones no son buenas o son por completo incorrectas no porque tengan errores de gramática sino porque significan otra cosa completamente diferente:

> "ayudado por nuestros estudios..."
>   "en el cuadro de nuestros estudios"

Frases que puedes usar en esta situación serían:

> como parte de nuestros estudios...
>   para complementar y mejorar
>   nuestros estudios...
>   como complemento de nuestros estudios ...

y esas serían traducciones más o menos literales. También podías decirlo así:

> para enriquecer nuestros estudios...
>   para enriquecer nuestra
>   experiencia...
>   para incrementar nuestro conocimiento...

en fin, pudes tener muchísimas opciones.

Answer (score -3):

Me gusta utilizar **Plan de estudios** Esto es equivalente al cien por ciento a lo que dices como cuadro de estudios.

Comment: **Plan de estudios** no es preciso lo que quiero porque hay la implicación que es un parte de mi curso ¿O no? pero es una buen traducción, gracias.

Comment: Pero es en la pregunta no es tan importante que se refiera a los estudios, simplemente es cómo decir mejor que una cosa forma parte de otra.